# How to send symbol as method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Example,

I'll use a Rails ActiveRecord Callback

```
before_validation :foobar

def foobar
 logger.debug 'before validate'
end
```

if i send the method as `symbol` this callback executes well.

My question is, this is not a normal case!

Ruby cannot send method as param, except `block, Proc, lambda`, isn't it?

This is reasonable for me.

```
before_validation -> {logger.debug 'before validate'}
```

But how could this work?

```
before_validation :foobar
```

So i made my own methods, same as this.

```
  do_something(:my_callback)

  def do_something(my_callback)
    my_callback
    logger.debug "somesomesome"
  end

  def my_callback
    logger.debug "calcalcalcal"
  end
```

and the result is?

ofcourse, this is not working!

my_callback param is just a plain symbol :(

Comment: You need to actually send the message in the `do_something_method`: `send(my_callback)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-send):

```
def do_something(my_callback)
  send my_callback
end
```

or if you want it to be more generic (so you can pass arguments/block to it:

```
def do_something(my_callback, *args, &block)
  send my_callback, *args, &block
end
```

Comment: oh....so if i search the core inside ActiveRecord it will use send?! never guesssed that!

Comment: @Canna yes, `send` is commonly used inside `ActiveRecord`.

Answer (score 2):

Symbols are useful because a given symbol name refers to the same object throughout a Ruby program.
There are three ways to call method in ruby:

1)**Dot operator**

```
object = Object.new
puts object.object_id
 #=> 282660
```

2)**Using send** ([API](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/__send__) )

```
puts object.send(:object_id)
 #=> 282660
```

3)**Using method.call**

```
puts object.method(:object_id).call
 #=> 289744
```

So here the symbol `:object_id` can also be a reference to your method such as  `:my_callback`